# Android 2.3.x ZXing odd behaviour

Tags: android, zxing

I'm developing an application for delievery service and as one of features it has is scanning barcode on shipment's waybill. I'm using `ZXing` library for this function - I have imported ZXing as library project in my app. All works great but I've faced with strange behavior on Android 2.3.x - both devices and emulators:
1) I have an `MainActivity` **with image background** (setted using `android:background` property of my root `RelativeLayout`) - after button click I'll launch an Intent to scan barcode. And I get next picture instead of `ViewfinderView`
[image]

As you can see - empty screen with my background from first activity and `TextView` from `CaptureActivity` of `ZXing`

2) After this I change background of MainActivity to **solid color** - and all works as expected.
3) Devices and Emu with Android 4.x also works good.

Can anyone explain what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing background file format from `jpg` to `png`. If somebody interesting to test it I'll share code.

Answer (score 0):

Your image didn't come through.

*This is presumably because you've copied and pasted our app without really understanding it. Please don't copy `android/` directly as you may be copying things that harm us, like the manifest.*

You'll probably have to clarify a lot more about what you're doing. For example, your app wil not show in the background if it has been backgrounded because you launched an `Intent`. My best guess is that you've copied `CaptureActivity` with a transparent background but have not successfully put camera data onto it. If it's a separate `Activity`, then `MainActivity` is irrelevant. But that doesn't match what you describe.